# .htaccess redirect example.com to example.com/admin_panel

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect from "example.com", "www.example.com", "example2.com" and "www.example2.com" to "https://example.com/admin_panel/", i tried this:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^www.example2.eu/index\.php
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^www.example.eu/index\.php [OR]
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^example2.eu/index\.php [OR]
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^example.eu/index\.php [OR]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.eu/admin_panel/index\.php$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

but it does not work

Comment: For sure the `[OR]` operators are placed oddly, you need to have one after the first condition and none after the last one.

Comment: Apart from that: `%{THE_REQUEST}` does _not_ contain the host name of the request, but only the requested path. That is clearly documented. Didn't you _read_ the documentation of the tool you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague, since it contains contradictions. For example it is unclear how you want to treat the paths in the requests. Is `/index.php` a requirement for the rewriting to get applied or not?

Given that little and vague information I can only point you into the rough direction:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example2\.eu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example2\.eu$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.eu$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.eu/admin_panel/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.eu$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/admin_panel
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.eu/admin_panel/$1 [R=301]
```

Note that I *removed* the condition testing for the host name "www.example.eu" since it would lead to an endless rewriting rule.

The given code snippet is only meant as a starting point. It should work, but I did not test it myself. It should work likewise from the http servers host configuration or inside dynamic configuration files (".htaccess").

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: i'm getting "too many redirects error", and in link it's `https://example.eu/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/admin_panel/ ...`

Comment: No, I doubt you really used the code I posted. I assume you used a modified version that still contains all four host names in the conditions? There is a reason why I changed that, since that _obviously_ needs to result in an endless rewriting loop. Have a try using the code snippet I actually provided, not something looking similar, and work from there.